# How to play video at the same time on separate computers

Tags: video

Is there any easy way for two or more people to watch a video together on different computers, so that play/pause is synchronized?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[VideoLAN VLC Player](http://www.videolan.org/vlc/) has options for broadcasting a/v.

You can stream the media by opening VLC Player and clicking Media > Streaming. Then set your options. Use the [streaming section](http://www.videolan.org/vlc/streaming.html) of VideoLAN's site if you need help.

Once you're streaming your video, you can connect the other device to the stream (probably using VLC, as well). As long as you've selected "play locally" it should be playing on both devices at the same time.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

http://wiki.videolan.org/Documentation:Modules/netsync

It can help you synchronise the play/pause controlled from the master

Answer (score 0):

https://youtu.be/TPZTbD4bd4I

Same Play is doing that, and to change video type: changevid example.mp4 and press enter.

Comment: Can you give summary of the video, instead of just putting the link here?

Answer (score 0):

[SyncTube](https://sync-tube.de/) has a simple interface, but it works perfectly for group watching YouTube videos. Create a room and you can immediately start watching YouTube videos. Search for a video or paste in a URL using the bar at the top. Any new video will automatically be added to the room's playlist.

More Info. [Make use of Blog](https://www.makeuseof.com/tag/watch-youtube-together/)